# Nest JS v10 breakpoints not working on VSCode

Tags: nestjs

After upgrating a nest application to v10 for build application with SWC, VSCode launch.json not working as expectedly

VSCode breakpoints should be work.

Current launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Nest",
      "args": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts"
      ],
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "start:dev",
        "--",
        "--inspect-brk"
      ],
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: adding "sourceMaps": true to .swcrc solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

For anybody in doubt, this is how `.swcrc` and `launch.json` looks and work in our case:

**.swcrc**

```json
{
  "jsc": {
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "typescript",
      "decorators": true
    },
    "transform": {
      "legacyDecorator": true,
      "decoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "target": "es2017",
    "keepClassNames": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@ogma/*": ["packages/*/src/"]
    }
  },
  "module": {
    "type": "commonjs",
    "strictMode": true
  },
  "sourceMaps": true
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to process",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true,
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

And then we start the dev server like so: `nest start -b swc -w --debug`